# How to get Javascript auto completion for string parameters in vscode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

How can we get parameter autocompletion for string parameters in vscode for JavaScript?

I know how to achieve this in TypeScript. We can do that by assigning the options as types

[image]

I think this should be possible because vscode supports this for native functions such as `addEventListener`

[image]

Comment: You know, TypeScript core library has the type definitions for "native functions", so VS Code shows hints for all functions with defined typings. You can try JSDoc for JavaScript

Comment: @NailAchmedzhanov thanks for that, I was able to figure out how to do this using JSDoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NailAchmedzhanov I was able to figure it out using JSDoc for JavaScript.

[image]